# Getting github project upload error

Tags: git, github

I'm uploading project on github. But i am getting this error:

```
Can't connect to any repository:
https://github.com/... (https://github.com/..: Error writing request body to server)
```

Is this error normal or What is the solution to solve.?

Comment: You need to provide the full URL otherwise it's unclear what you problem is.

Comment: If you can use SSH from your network, try using the SSH URL instead of the HTTPS one. (It should be `git@github.com:«username»/«reponame».git`.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Eclipse, then do following steps :

```
 Open Eclipse > Select Git Repositories Perspective
    Right click on yourRepository > Properties > Configuration > AddEntry (Key = https.postBuffer, Value = 52428800000 )
```

Click Ok.
Try push again.

Comment: Who says he's using Eclipse?

Comment: Doing this completely broke my Eclipse configuration and I had to delete my .git file. :(

Comment: Solved my issue. I was trying to push around 1500 files at a time from eclipse. Adding entry for https.postBuffer solved the issue.